# Unhandled exception in FutureBuilder Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

i try to use `FutureBuilder` widget in `flutter` to get some data from network. for this i use below code :

```
Future<List<Product>> getWishList() async {
http.Response response = await http.post(
  MY_URL,
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  List<Product> ret = List();
  Map<String, dynamic> result;
  try {
    result = json.decode(response.body);
    for (var i = 0; i < result['data'].length; i++) {
        ret.add(Product.fromJson(result['data'][i]));
    }
    return ret;
  } catch (e) {
    return throw Exception("Json parse error");
  }
} else {
  return throw Exception("network connection failed");
}
}
```

AND:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getWishList(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                  if(snapshot.hasError){
                    controller.forward(from: 0.0);
                    return Material(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 36.0),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: FadeTransition(
                          opacity: animation,
                          child: PButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              setState(() {
                                getWishList();
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.perm_scan_wifi,color: Colors.black,size: 76.0,),
                                SizedBox(height:24.0),
                                Text("Try again",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,color: const Color(0XFF222222)),),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }else{
                    return new ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap:(){
                                setState(() {
                                  getWishList();
                                });
                              },
                              child: new Text("Every thing ok"))
                        ]);
                  }
              }else{
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 36.0),
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                );
              }
            })
```

now if http response return error in first time every thing good but with click on `Try again` and if error again this message display on console:

> [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception: Exception:
>   network connection failed
>         _WishListState.getWishList (package:parchino/screen/screen_wish_list.dart:127:14) 
>         _WishListState.build...
>   (package:parchino/screen/screen_wish_list.dart:65:33)
>         State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1130:30)
>         _WishListState.build.. (package:parchino/screen/screen_wish_list.dart:64:31)
>         GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
>         TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
>         TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
>         PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
>         PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart<…>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `setState`, you mark the widget as Dirty and basically tells the framework to rebuild it but only after `getWishList` has been called (the one inside `setState`). As it is an `async` method, it launches quickly and rebuild the widget.

By rebuilding the widget, you rebuild the `FutureBuilder` which tries to evaluate its future. As the future is a function, it calls it and makes a new call to `getWishList`.

That makes two calls to the same method and thus two calls to an http server very quickly. Those calls are probably in conflict, and throws an error.

You should not invoke a `Future` directly in the `FutureBuilder` but use a [previously-obtained](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) `Future` instead.

```
Future<List<Product>> myFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  myFuture = getWishList();
  super.initState();
}

Future<List<Product>> getWishList() async {
 //Do your stuff
}
```

Then in your build, set `myFuture` as the future of the `FutureBuilder` and in your `setState`, set `myFuture` again:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: myFuture,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      //...
      setState(() {
        myFuture = getWishList();
      });
      //...
  }
);
```

That will make the `setState` set a new future in `myFuture` and ask the widget to rebuilt itself. As the `FutureBuilder` rebuild, it evaluates `myFuture` instead of calling http once again.